# Como convertir solo el primer caracter en mayusculas en c++?

Tags: c++

Necesito crear un codigo en donde pueda ingresar tres o mas palabras y esas al mostrarmelos el caracter inicial siempre sea en mayuscula sin importar como se haya ingresado  **EJ:**
**Entrada**
maRIAna

**salida**
Mariana

tengo entendido que puedo utilizar un for, lo que no se es si puedo utilizar la funcion toupper y  tolower en C++

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Aquí no tenemos por costumbre hacerle los deberes a nadie. Debes investigar y currártelo un poco. Muestra el código que llevas hasta el momento y pregunta dudas concretas en base a ese código. Te sugiero pasarte por [ask] y por el [tour] para entender cómo funciona este sitio

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que existen librerías que proporcionan funciones para ello como el `toupper()` y el `tolower()`.

En un post de respuesta a una pregunta de este foro, se da un ejemplo con `for` y para ello se usa el siguiente código:

```
if( !nombre.empty() )
{
    nombre[0] = std::toupper( nombre[0] );

    for( std::size_t i = 1 ; i < nombre.length() ; ++i )
        nombre[i] = std::tolower( name[i] );
}
```

Donde:

- Con la conddicional `if` se valida que el nombre ingresado no sea vacío.
- Una vez validado, se coloca en mayúscula la primera letra del nombre con la función `toupper()`.
- Finalmente se inicializa el bucle `for` tomando como referencia un contador iniciado en la segunda letra del nombre (`i=1`) que a su vez tiene como límite la cantidad (`length`) de caracteres que tiene el nombre. A cada uno de los subsiguientes caracteres se le aplica la función `tolower()`.

> Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018961/capitalize-the-first-letter-lower-case-the-rest

Answer (score 0):

si deseas convertir la primera letra a Mayúscula puedes hacer uso el método llamado toUpperCase() lo que permite cambiar el string a mayuscula, devolviéndote una cadena con tu palabra(s) indicada.

Comment: No creo que una función propia de JS o Java vaya a servir en C++...